# Storing data values in multiple tables vs accessing the same value via query

Tags: sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have designed my database tables where multiple tables store a value, all of which could be achieved via a query to one table.

My question is would it be considered better practice to never store duplicate data and always query, or to store small values multiple times to reduce the number of queries required?

For context, I am building a Python app that quizzes Korean language questions using SQLAlchemy and SQLite.

I have User , Quiz and Question classes.

The values in question are num_correct, num_wrong with regard to quiz questions.

Basically I have a question table that stores all questions related to quiz by quiz_id. Each question has a column "correct" that stores a boolean telling whether or not that question was answered correctly.

In my "quiz" table, I have columns for num_correct / num_wrong regarding questions answered for that quiz.

In my "user" table, I also have columns for num_correct / num_wrong regarding their total answers correct and wrong for all time.

I realize that to get the values in "quiz" I could query the "questions" table and to get the values in "user" I could do that same.

In this case (and in general) which would be the preferred strategy considering best practices?

I've tried googling quite a bit, but wording the question is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue of duplicated data is a complicated one in relational databases.  If your application is doing data modifications, then duplicated data incurs synchronization issues -- the data needs to be updated in multiple places.

That is bad for a variety of reasons:

- Updating a single item of information requires multiple changes.
- The multiple changes can get out-of-sync, meaning that queries will not see consistent data.
- Changes to the database structure (such as adding new tables) can be rather cumbersome.

Databases *do* support this capability, via ACID properties, transactions, and triggers.  However, they add overhead.  In general, such duplication is added out of necessity (i.e. performance) rather than up-front.  Hence, there is a strong preference for *normalized* data models where information is stored only once when updates frequently occur.

On the other hand, some databases are used primarily for querying purposes.  These databases are often denormalized -- and quite so.  For instance, a customer table might contain summaries along many different dimensions, gathering information from dozens of underlying tables.

This not only simplifies queries but it *encodes business logic*.  One major issue with using data is that different people have slightly different definitions of things -- is a one-year customer someone who started 365 days ago?  Someone who started on the same day of the year last year?  Someone who has been around for 12 months?  Standardized analysis tables provide the answer.

Your case seems to fall more into the first situation.  You are doing updates and thinking about storing summaries up front.  I would discourage you from doing this.  Just write the queries you need to summarize the data.  In all likelihood, indexes and partitioning will provide all the performance you need.

If you know up front that you will have millions of users taking hundreds of quizzes with dozens of questions, then you might want to think about performance optimizations up front.  But for thousands of users taking a handful of quizzes with a few dozen questions, start with a simple data model and make it more complicated *after you have demonstrated that it works*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional information. That perfectly answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is would it be considered better practice to never store duplicate data and always query, or to store small values multiple times to reduce the number of queries required?

I don't see how this reduces the number of queries.

It may affect the *complexity* of a query, i.e. you'll need to join a few tables together instead of a simple query on one table, but these operations are very fast.  I would not worry about speed.

If you duplicate your data it **will** eventually get out of sync, and then you're in big trouble.

In short, don't duplicate.

Also, this question doesn't really have anything to do with Python.